# Handle different readers differently in a Linux Character Driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver

I'm working on a Linux character driver which needs to provide different data to different readers when read. This is so that I can implement a kind of key-value store.

The interface would work something along the lines of:

```bash
# from terminal 1
echo "test" > /dev/key # tell the driver which
cat /dev/value # read the value associated with "test"
```

```bash
# from terminal 2
echo "other_key" > /dev/key
cat /dev/value
```

The idea here is that, internally, the driver would keep track of which key each reader has requested, and then upon reading, return the value associated with that key.

The problem here is that I'm unsure how to check which process is reading/writing.

I'm assuming that if this data is available, it'll be in the `struct file *` that's passed to the read and write functions, but as far as I can tell there's no relevant field in that struct.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to support the concept that a process can open() your device to get a file descriptor. The requests are associated with the descriptor, which holds the context information to provide the right value for the key.

Comment: Your shell examples cannot work because they don't use the same descriptor. The only way we could plausibly connect the `echo` and `cat` action together is that they are in the same shell session and have a common grandparent process.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping for, but looking at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h#L940 I cannot find where to find the descriptor that someone is using to read the file

Comment: In response to your second comment - why would they have to use the same descriptor? Aren't they both still accessing the same driver?

Comment: I think maybe look at `divers/char/mem.c`.  You implement a `struct fops`, and the read operation takes a `struct file *` argument.

Comment: A `struct file` object has a `void *private_data` pointer where a driver can stick some extending information.

Comment: Even though you have one driver, there is a requirement to have multiple conversation threads with it. We want to open a conversation, write a key, and then obtain the corresponding value, regardless of who else is writing what keys to the driver at the same time. The obvious locus for that conversation is the file descriptor; though that model isn't a good fit for the shell scripting examples.

Comment: It is possible to open a file for reading and writing in the shell, e.g. `exec 3<>/dev/keyvalue ;` `echo "test" >&3 ;` `cat <&3 ;`. Most shells do not support seeking/rewinding of file descriptors, so this is only suitable for unseekable files. The `struct file`'s `private_data` can be used to store information private to each open file description if `/dev/keyvalue` is opened multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott, I like the idea of storing private info in private_data - I'll just clarify that, although in my example I access the file from the shell, that isn't strictly necessary behaviour, I mainly want to be able to use the driver from an application.